# What is "entry point" in npm init

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an empty new project, when i run npm init i got a list of questions to answer, for example:

```
name: (karma)
version: (1.0.0)
description:my project description
entry point: (index.js)
```

I am really confused about the one that says "entry point", Should this be my index.html file or my app.js or is it something else?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Quoting from this [blog post](http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2013/04/23/create-your-first-node-module-and-publish-it-to-the-npm-registry/):

> **Entry point** is the javascript file that will be invoked when consumers
>   of your module “require” it, this file will include the main logic for
>   your module, or if it is a large module you can export public
>   functions found with other files (typically in the lib directory)

So it should be your `app.js` file.

Comment: @leezor, so do we need to add index.js or app.js manually on specific module folder or it will get created while executing npm command ?

Comment: What about when we have a private repository that shouldn't be consumed for other repositories, when we're talking about a simple single project, should we specify what on the entry point? Or how to leave it empty?

Comment: @giovannipds, just delete the `main` key and set `private` flag to `true`. You should be good.

Answer (score 7):

For any project, entry point is the file from which execution starts. It depends on project configuration and run time environment of the technology we are using.

Examples : For a node.js project **app.js** is used initializes the app and glues everything together.

Comment: @Mahesh,  so do we need to add index.js or app.js manually on specific module folder or it will get created while executing npm command ?

Comment: Yes. If you create node.js project with express generator. It will create app.js by itself with some base project template. Use npm install express-generator -g to create a project.

Answer (score 2):

Entry point is the path that your users will access using the index.js to be able to access the full view and services of your module I will rather leave it the way it is if you do not know what you are doing.