# Customise Bulma with node-sass: npm init entry point confusion

Tags: npm, sass, bulma

In Bulma documentation (https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/) it says to do an `npm init` and **when prompted for an entry point, enter `sass/mystyles.scss`.** I understand from previous post ([What is "entry point" in npm init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800066/what-is-entry-point-in-npm-init)) that entry point during `npm init` should be your main.js file.

Why does Bulma documentation recommend making the custom scss file the entry point?

I'm keeping project entry point at main.js, but unsure of implications (if any).

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

It **doesn't** matter as long as your project isn't meant to be installed as a dependency.

**The longer answer**

To clearify what you read in the post about the [NPM entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800097/8918893):

The entry is used when users install **your** package from NPM and requires it. This means that if your entry is `main.js`,

```
const package = require("yourpackage");
```

will be the same as writing

```
const package = require("./node_modules/yourpackage/main");
```

Because you don't need this syntax inside your project, it doesn't affect anything, like compiling Sass, inside your project.

---

If the package is supposed to be published and installed as a dependency, however, you have to think about your entry point. If the project is primarily a Sass/SCSS package, I'd recommend setting the value to your main Sass/SCSS file, as **there are Sass/SCSS processors that make use of the entry point**.

That's also why the Bulma docs recommend setting the entry point to the Sass file. But in the end, it's your decision.