# What should the entry point be for a pure CSS npm project?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I have a CSS file that I want to upload to npm. My project's folder structure is as follows:

```
my-project (folder)
|
+---- css (folder)
      |
      +---- my-project.css
      |
      +---- my-project.min.css
```

When I try to upload my project to NPM, it asks for an entry point, where the default is set to `index.js`. For my case where there are only 2 files inside a folder called `css`, what should it be? Moreover, what is the meaning of the entry-point for an npm project?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32800066/3001761? If you're not expecting your users to `require` your package, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Entry point is a JavaScript file that gets called when your module is needed.
By common practice, it is usually given the name "app.js" or "index.js" (your case).
The entry point is also the path that will be used to access your module.
CSS files cannot be entry points.

Comment: The default is `index.js`, which doesn't exist in the OP's package, so needs to be changed.